# Highcharts angular 2 with observables http request

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart working with observables comming from http request, the following code is working with some fake datas I just would like to replace them by true datas comming from a backend-end script here's my code:

my app.ts:

```
export class MyVerticalchartComponent  {


   @Input() showMePartially: boolean;

  options: Object;

  constructor(public userService3: UserService3) {

       this.options = {
        title : { text : '' },
        chart: {  type: 'area' },
        legend: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime',
              //    startOnTick: true,
              //    endOnTick: true,
              //    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            },
                  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M:%S',
            hour: '%H:%M:%S',
            day: '%H:%M:%S',
            week: '%H:%M:%S',
            month: '%H:%M:%S',
            year: '%H:%M:%S'
        },
        yAxis: { min: 0,
          max: 100 },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
          //  pointStart: 0,
              color: '#648e59',
              fillOpacity: 0.8,
              fillColor: '#648e59'
                  }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Someone1',
          **data: [ // here should come my Observable !!
        [1497837618,0],[1497837738,0],[1497837858,0],[1497837978,0],[1497838098,0],[1497838218,0],[1497838338,0],[1497838458,0]    ],**
        }]
    };
}
```

}

my app.html:

```
 <chart [options]="options">
      <series>
     </series>
  </chart>
```

my http service.ts:

```
export interface User3 {
 data: any;
}
const usersURL = 'http://my.super.backend.script.com';
```

@Injectable()
export class UserService3 {

users3: Observable;

```
constructor (public http: Http) {

          const tick3$ = Observable.timer(100, 60000);

      this.users3 = tick3$.flatMap(() => http.get(usersURL)).map(res => [res.json()]).publishBehavior(<User3[]>[]).refCount();

}
}
```

my json looks like:

```
  "operating_details":[[1497837618,0],[1497837738,0],[1497837858,0],
  [1497837978,0],[1497838098,0],[1497838218,0],[1497838338,0],
  [1497838458,0],[1497838578,0],[1497838698,0],[1497838818,0],
  [1497838938,0],[1497839058,0],[1497839178,0],[1497839298,0],
  [1497839418,0],[1497839538,0],[1497839658,0],[1497839778,0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to move the observer into separate method

```
getData() {
     const tick3$ = Observable.timer(100, 60000);

     return tick3$.flatMap(() => this.http.get(usersURL)).map(res => [res.json()]).publishBehavior(<User3[]>[]).refCount();

}
```

in your component in the `ngOnInit` method to call the observer

```
public ngOnInit () {
   this.userService3.getData().subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(this.options); // to see the strcture
     console.log(data); // to see the response

     this.options.series[0].data = data;
   });
}
```

Edited

Comment: many thanks for your quick answear...sounds good to me I'm tring right now !

Comment: For the method getData() should I had it in my constructor? because it generate me errors..

Comment: If I put the method outside of mmy constructor my vs code says: [ts] Cannot find name 'http'.
any (first error) and [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'.
any (second)

Comment: I suppose it's because my http is injected in my constructor

Comment: ... if you are asking, where should you put it ... it should be in your service outside the constructor (next to it).. I have edited my answer

Comment: I agree but got then got two errors: one with the http and one with Jason (highlighted in red)

Comment: oh.. ! I didn't sorry !

Comment: now it sound better :) in the service it works, I am trying in the component  with the chart ! Thanks again for your help !

Comment: It almost works, I just got an error with "series" (highlighted red) error :[ts] Property 'series' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: this is the path to `data` property `options.series[0].data` if you put the option object in your console without the ** in the you have putted you can see its structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147448/discussion-between-emile-cantero-and-yordan-nikolov).